# Checking if contact form's works (automated testing)

Tags: php, wordpress, automation, automated-tests, contact-form

I have a website with a contact formular. It's vital for my business, that I get *all* messages, that are being sent by this formular. And I've seen SOOO many examples of contact forms breaking due to dependency-updates or script collisions.

So my plan was to make an automated test, that will fill out a contact formular every day, ensuring that there's no errors. And also (and most importantly), checking that the message is received in the other end.

I'm using WordPress [Formidable forms](https://formidableforms.com/), but it's okay, if it's something that needs to be custom made. I've previously used [Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) with [Flamingo](https://wordpress.org/plugins/flamingo/), which was good. But the downside was, that if I didn't receive an email, then it failed silently, - and then I could recover non-received messages with Flamingo. And I need to know *immidiately*, if messages doesn't arrive in my inbox.

### Checking the front-end

In order to ensure that the form doesn't break, before the mail was sent, then I'm planning to do it using [Nightwatchjs](http://nightwatchjs.org/).

### Checking that the message is received

This is the part that I'm not sure how to do... Verifying the sending/receiving part.

So if my main e-mail was inbox@example.org, then I was thinking, that if I could setup an extra mail, like robot@example.org, and then send all mails to both emails, - and then... Ehm... Do something with that?

How do I do this? 
Or are there any frameworks for this, that will make it easier?

Comment: I'd use selenium or any other tool which you can use to interact with your website programmatically - then after a period of minutes or so, smtp into your mailserver and check for new formular entries (ie. let them all be filled out by a specific sender mail address so you may identify them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current scenario, there are 3 important things which you should consider while testing.

But before that, don't completely rely upon emails to alert you. Make sure whenever a form is submitted, backend persists the data in some DB and then email is triggered or both can happen parallelly.

Automating UI/functional tests can be time-consuming and also expensive. So I would suggest you break down your testing in two sections.

1. First can be direct API testing, these tests can contain all
   business logic & scenarios, like sending invalid/empty fields, XSS,
   injections, etc. Now,  using the persisted data you can assert very easily.
2. Second can be your functional test cases, you can use puppeteer or
   selenium, puppeteer is more lightweight and flexible. Just write some
   basic form filling tests, then login to wp-admin and assert/verify the
   data.
3. I would suggest running the above test cases in some
   UAT or different environment, this will make sure that only your test cases are creating the records in the DB and not someone else. Also using a different environment can benefit you to easily mock your email server or use [mailgun API](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-events.html#how-to-start-tracking-email-events) for verifying emails delivery.